# What is the word for doing a mission?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to describe the "doing" of a new mission.

In context, I would like to say something like (or hear as an announcement in the news):

> The Bohemian Space Agency has just ____ a new satellite mission to
>   planet X.

Here the missing word should be related to mission, and *not* to satellite.

I have some ideas of my own, but I don't want to be suggestive, or write the answer into the body of the question.

Comment: Not really clear to me what type of "doing" you want.  Is "started" or "commenced" appropriate?

Comment: "Started" would be one of my own choices, yes. It is an event which just hit the news, so yes, one might say that. Although, for some reason, it doesn't feel like the right choice. You might want to propose "commenced" as an answer.

Comment: You can answer your own question and also provide suggestions as it gives us some insight into what you've been thinking and what you have researched so far.

Comment: embarked on????

Comment: 'Mission' is used, albeit rarely, as a verb: *The Bohemian Space Agency has just missioned a new satellite to planet X.*

Answer (score 1):

Try [carry out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carry%20out) or carrying out (if still in action or the mission hasn't finished)

> to bring to a successful issue  (carried out the satellite mission)
>
> to put into execution
>
> to continue to an end or stopping point

Also see [get off the ground](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/get-off-the-ground-or-get-something-off-the-ground) - to start something, to begin something, to make a beginning, to succeed or begin to succeed, start or cause to start happening or functioning (usually successfully)

I have mentioned all the possible meanings from several sites. 
The sentence "got the satellite mission off the ground, " unintentionally, both as a metaphor and actual event, means to star or begin.

Comment: Well, I could agree with you that my wording wasn't crystal clear, but these words are used once you [are] *done* [with] something. "Doing" a satellite mission could take a long time...

Comment: @Matsmath you can use "carrying out, " which says that the action isn't finished.

Answer (score 1):

@Matsmath's comment is right on. It probably depends on what phase of the mission the sentence relates to. First, the BSA will have ***announced*** the mission, then that they had ***launched*** it (or perhaps ***postponed*** or ***delayed*** it due to unforeseen glitches), then to @vickyace's ***carried out*** or ***completed*** their mission (although it would no longer be new by that time). As we know from the news, these missions can take many years.

Comment: Refering to project initiation, BSA also **planned** the mission.

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

started/began -- as proposed by TrevorD

launched -- this sounds (for me) just right, but you launch a satellite, not a mission.

Comment: Metaphorically, a mission is and can be launched.

Comment: Don't you think that using "launch" would sound like a childish word play? Something "catchy" you would rather use in the front page of a tabloid, but not in the national newspaper.

Comment: Does "launching an operation" sound weird? It doesn't. Read, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_in_Afghanistan_(2001–14), which has a line "The request was dismissed by the U.S. as a delaying tactic, and on 7 October 2001 it launched operation enduring freedom with the UK."

Comment: No, that's certainly not. But here I am launching something what actually can be launched :-). The downvoter care to elaborate on their problem?

Comment: I believe that can be amusing, confusing, redundant or whatever but the point is that "satellite mission" is a compound noun and it ultimately depends on the speaker whether they want to portray it just as a launch or a mission.